# What tools are best for monitoring celery tasks besides flower?

Tags: celery, django-celery, prometheus

We would like to monitor celery tasks, but with more than just flower.  We want to be able to send emails when a task fails and record the average task runtime, visualize the success rate, failure rate, etc.

Would Prometheus be a great tool for this?  If so, how straightforward is it to setup with a django app that uses several celery tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus is a good option for for this. You would need to use the [celery-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/zerok/celery-prometheus-exporter) to export metrics on celery tasks. You would then need to scrape the data by adding a [scrape config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) to prometheus.

Once these steps are working you can set up [alerts](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/) in Prometheus. When these are triggered they send alerts to the [alert manager](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/) which can forward them to whatever channels you want - slack, pagerduty, email, etc

Setting up all of this is quite involved.